# How to keep a cumulative count of changes across row elements, ignoring NaNs, and creating a separate column with the results

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame that looks like this:

| Identification | Date (day/month/year) | X | Y |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 01/01/2022 | NaN | abc |
| 123 | 02/01/2022 | 200 | acb |
| 123 | 03/01/2022 | 200 | ary |
| 124 | 01/01/2022 | 200 | abc |
| 124 | 02/01/2022 | NaN | abc |
| 124 | 03/01/2022 | NaN | NaN |

I am trying to create two separate 'change' columns, one for x and y separately, that is keeping a rolling count of how many times a given element is changing over time. I would like my output to look something like this, where NaN ---> NaN is not counted as a change but NaN ---> *some element* is counted:

| Identification | Date (day/month/year) | X | Y | Change X | Change Y |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 01/01/2022 | NaN | abc | 0 | 0 |
| 123 | 02/01/2022 | 200 | acb | 1 | 1 |
| 123 | 03/01/2022 | 200 | ary | 1 | 2 |
| 124 | 01/01/2022 | 200 | abc | 0 | 0 |
| 124 | 02/01/2022 | NaN | abc | 1 | 0 |
| 124 | 03/01/2022 | NaN | NaN | 1 | 1 |

Thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a classical comparison with the next item (obtained with [`groupby.shift`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.shift.html)) combined with a [`groupby.cumsum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.cumsum.html), however a NaN compared with another NaN yields `False`. To overcome this, we can first [`fillna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html) with an object that is not part of the dataset. Here I chose `object`, it could be `-1` if your data is strictly positive.

```
def change(s):
    s = s.fillna(object)
    return (s.ne(s.groupby(df['Identification']).shift())
            .groupby(df['Identification']).cumsum().sub(1)
            )

out = df.join(df[['X', 'Y']].apply(change).add_prefix('Change '))

print(out)
```

Output:

```
   Identification Date (day/month/year)      X    Y  Change X  Change Y
0             123            01/01/2022    NaN  abc         0         0
1             123            02/01/2022  200.0  acb         1         1
2             123            03/01/2022  200.0  ary         1         2
3             124            01/01/2022  200.0  abc         0         0
4             124            02/01/2022    NaN  abc         1         0
5             124            03/01/2022    NaN  NaN         1         1
```

Comment: @Anoushiravan glad you like it ;)

Comment: This answer suits my needs perfectly, thank you! If possible, would you mind explaining in a little bit more detail your function? I am not familiar with many of the methods (ne, shift, sub) you used

Comment: I suggest you read the documentation of the functions you don't know. I'll add some links, then let me know if you have a specific question.